# Não consigo deixar o id automático dentro da Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu tenho uma procedure de inserir dados, mas eu tenho que deixar a inserção do ID automático. Já yentei de várias formas e não está indo.

Já usei o `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

O que eu faço para funcionar?

A frase do erro é essa:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IdColaborador', table
> 'smningatreinamentogrupo2.dbo.ContatoColaborador'; column does not
> allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Mas eu quero de forma que eu não preciso colocar no EXEC pois tenho que depois pesquisar no select com o Id

**ESSE É O CÓDIGO:**

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_InsEmColaborador]( 
        @NomeColaborador VARCHAR (120),
        @DataNascimento DATE,
        @DataAdmissao DATE,
        @DataDemissao DATE = NULL,
        @IdPoloEmpresa TINYINT,
        @IdCargo TINYINT,
        @IdCidadeColaborador SMALLINT,
        @DDD TINYINT,
        @Numero INT,
        @Whatsapp BIT,
        @Email VARCHAR(150),
        @Id SMALLINT
        )

        AS
        /* 
        DOCUMENTAÇÃO
        ARQUIVO FONTE....: SP_SP_InsEmColaborador.sql
        OBJETIVO.........: INSERIR DADOS NA TABELA COLABORADOR.
        AUTOR............: SMN - JÚLIA EVELYN
        DATA.............: 11/12/2023
        EX...............: EXEC [dbo].[SP_InsEmColaborador] @NomeColaborador = 'Júlia Evelyn', @DataNascimento = '20050421', @DataAdmissao = '20230801',
                           @DataDemissao = NULL, @IdPoloEmpresa = 1, @IdCargo = 1, @IdCidadeColaborador = 1, @DDD = 83, @Numero = 9918745, @Whatsapp = 0, @Email = 'julia.smn@gmail.com'
                           
        */

        DECLARE @IdColaborador SMALLINT 
        SET @IdColaborador = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS ((SELECT 1 FROM ContatoColaborador
            WHERE Email = @Email))
                BEGIN 
                    INSERT INTO ContatoColaborador (DDD, Numero, Whatsapp, Email, IdContatoColaborador)
                    VALUES (@DDD, @Numero, @Whatsapp, @Email, @IdCidadeColaborador) 
            END 
          ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO Colaborador (NomeColaborador, DataNascimento, DataAdmissao, DataDemissao, IdPoloEmpresa, IdCargo, Id) 
                    VALUES (@NomeColaborador, @DataNascimento, @DataAdmissao, @DataDemissao, @IdPoloEmpresa, @IdCargo, @IdColaborador)
                    INSERT INTO ContatoColaborador (DDD, Numero, Whatsapp, Email, IdContatoColaborador)
                    VALUES (@DDD, @Numero, @Whatsapp, @Email, @IdCidadeColaborador) 
                END
        END 
GO
```

Comment: Júlia, faltam informações sobre as tabelas utilizadas no procedimento.

Answer (score 1):

A função `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` retorna o último valor de identidade inserido na sessão atual, mas no seu código está sendo utilizado imediatamente após a declaração de variável `@IdColaborador`. Isso não vai retornar o valor desejado, já que o `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` deve ser chamado após a inserção dos dados na tabela para obter o último valor gerado.

Seu código atual não está gerenciando corretamente o `@IdColaborador`. Antes de usar a variável `@IdColaborador`, você precisa inserir os dados na tabela Colaborador para obter o valor do identificador gerado automaticamente (caso a coluna de identidade esteja configurada).
Testa isso

```sql
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SP_InsEmColaborador]( 
    @NomeColaborador VARCHAR (120),
    @DataNascimento DATE,
    @DataAdmissao DATE,
    @DataDemissao DATE = NULL,
    @IdPoloEmpresa TINYINT,
    @IdCargo TINYINT,
    @IdCidadeColaborador SMALLINT,
    @DDD TINYINT,
    @Numero INT,
    @Whatsapp BIT,
    @Email VARCHAR(150),
    @IdColaborador SMALLINT OUTPUT -- Adicionando um parâmetro de saída para o ID do Colaborador
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; -- Inicia uma transação

    -- Inserir dados na tabela Colaborador para obter o ID gerado
    INSERT INTO Colaborador (NomeColaborador, DataNascimento, DataAdmissao, DataDemissao, IdPoloEmpresa, IdCargo)
    VALUES (@NomeColaborador, @DataNascimento, @DataAdmissao, @DataDemissao, @IdPoloEmpresa, @IdCargo);

    -- Obter o ID do Colaborador recém-inserido
    SET @IdColaborador = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Inserir dados na tabela ContatoColaborador
    INSERT INTO ContatoColaborador (DDD, Numero, Whatsapp, Email, IdContatoColaborador)
    VALUES (@DDD, @Numero, @Whatsapp, @Email, @IdColaborador);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION; -- Confirma a transação

    -- Se ocorrer algum erro, fazer rollback da transação
    -- ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END
```